# Get chain of parents with fs

Tags: node.js

I'd like to get an array of parents of current directory. Currently I'm doing this

```
function parseStructure(drive) {
    let structure = [];
    while (drive.length > 3) {
        structure.unshift(path.basename(drive));
        drive = path.dirname(drive);
    }
    drive = drive.substr(0, 1);
    structure.unshift(drive);

    return structure;
}
```

because `path.dirname('C:/')` returns `C:/`. This will probably work on Windows but most probably won't on Linux. How can I check if current directory is root?

This route `C:\Users\user\SO` should return array of `['C', 'Users', 'user', 'SO']` and this route `/usr/user/SO` should return array of `['usr', 'user', 'SO']`.

Comment: have you tried `path.resolve().split(path.sep)`?

Comment: Indeed, I didn't. If you wish you can post this as answer otherwise I will tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
path.resolve().split(path.sep);
// ['', 'home', 'myuser', 'mydir', 'my-nested-dir']
```

It will print array of directories to your current directory (`process.cwd()`)

To remove extra empty string at the very beginning you can slice this array:

```
path.resolve().split(path.sep).slice(1);
// ['home', 'myuser', 'mydir', 'my-nested-dir']
```